# AES decryption is always null

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, salt

I tried using salt to decrypt a `AES` encrypted message but it always returns `null` value. Can anyone look at it where am i doing wrong?

```
public static String decryptMessage(String encryptedMessage, String salt) {

  String decryptedMessage = null;
  String valueToDecrypt = encryptedMessage;
  try {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);


    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
      byte[] decodedValue = Base64.decodeBase64(valueToDecrypt);
      byte[] decVal = c.doFinal(decodedValue);
      decryptedMessage = new String(decVal).substring(salt.length());
      valueToDecrypt = decryptedMessage;
    }


  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

  }
  return decryptedMessage;
}

**EDIT:**
```

Here is corresponding encryption method which i assume, works.

```
private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final int ITERATIONS = 5;
    private static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[] { '1', '2', '3', '4',
            '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' };


    public static String encryptMessage(String message, String salt) {
        String encMessage = null;
        byte[] encVal = null;
        String messageWithSalt = null;
        try {
            Key key = generateKey();

            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

            for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
                messageWithSalt = salt + encMessage;
                encVal = c.doFinal(messageWithSalt.getBytes());
                byte[] encryptedValue = new Base64().encode(encVal);
                encMessage = new String(encryptedValue);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return encMessage;
    }
```

PS: ITERATION is NOT 0;

Comment: You forgot to post the corresponding encryption code.

Comment: @Leigh Well, with that `catch` statement you can assume that it will return null on any decryption error too :) Seriously though, each and every line has at least a mistake, possibly except the `Cipher getInstance()` method, I guess we'll know when we know the value of `ALGORITHM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i found the error. It was in the encryption method.  `encMessage` was `null` before the encryption process begins.  `String encMessage = message` did the trick. So the encryption method is:

```
 public static String encryptMessage(String message, String salt) {
            String encMessage = message;
            byte[] encVal = null;
            String messageWithSalt = null;
            try {
                Key key = generateKey();

                Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
                c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

                for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
                    messageWithSalt = salt + encMessage;
                    encVal = c.doFinal(messageWithSalt.getBytes());
                    byte[] encryptedValue = new Base64().encode(encVal);
                    encMessage = new String(encryptedValue);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return encMessage;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your method might be chronically broken or misnamed. You are generating a key each time you decrypt, whereas you should have a pre-existing key that matches the one used for encryption.

You also pass in a "salt" value - note: this is a term normally reserved for hashing - which you then completely ignore, except to use the size as a truncation length on your result.

Certainly what I see above is not decrypting anything in a sensible fashion. If you can describe *exactly* what you wanted to achieve, we can possibly correct the code or point you at the peer-reviewed method for performing that task (which may already be implemented in the standard libs).